# Can I perform a t-test to show that cluster means are different?

Tags: clustering, t-test, k-means

I'm looking at performing k-means clustering on a dataset with 5 continuous variables.  The clusters that I find however, look very similar except in one dimension e.g

cluster 1 : low avg income, low avg age ,high number of transactions

cluster 2: low avg income, low avg age, low number of transactions

cluster 3: high avg income, low avg age, low number of transactions

The "low avg age" for example, is different but in the same ballpark in each cluster, can I use a statistical test to test which ones are significantly different from each other?

If I wanted to compare the mean of another variable e.g. debt (£) (not used for clustering), does it make sense to use a t-test (or possibly something else) to test for significant difference in this variable between clusters?

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try a Hotelling's T test (assuming that they are jointly normal) and test all the means at once.

Comment: you may work out your study's objectives first !

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that k-means optimizes the sum of squares, which you'd also use in testing. This is called data snooping - I would expect the outcome to always be "significant", even if your I put data were uniform noise.

You could only test with attributes you did not use during clustering.